# INNER JOIN User, Database and Database Size using Mariadb in Centos 7

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, mariadb, centos7

Tho I can inner join the three by getting it from the processlist the problem is that processlists shows only the active connections / database . any idea where I can use other table except from processlist in information_schema and db in the mysql database. See image for the results of processlist. You can see that it only show the active database. 
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoV4T.png)

The query that I'm using ....

```
SELECT DB,USER,Round(sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 6) "Size in GB" FROM processlist INNER JOIN tables ON processlist.DB = tables.table_schema;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you are looking for.  But see if you like the output from

```
SELECT  table_schema AS DB,
        Round(sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 6) "Size in GB"
    FROM  information_schema.tables
    GROUP BY table_schema;
```